# structures' memory type and sizeof tip

Tags: c, memory, struct

for the structure

```
struct school {
char*name;
int student;
int teacher;
int worker;
};
```

I have actually two questions..

A)is the difference between x.y and x->y syntax that pointers point to an address in the heap memory between the other syntax deal with the stack 
or its not true and pointers can be used in structures to point to an address in the stack too , what is actually the difference between two syntax ?

B)when i try to print the sizeof the variable of the structure  it prints 24 not 20 could it be explained ?

Answer (score 2):

A) `x.y` is used when `x` is a variable of the structure type. `x->y` is used when `x` is a pointer to the structure type. It doesn't have to point to the heap, it can point to a variable. So if you have:

```
struct school school_var;
struct school *school_ptr = &school_var;
```

then `school_ptr->student` is the same as `school_var.student`.

B) Variables can have extra padding, which is included in `sizeof`.

Comment: when i make 
    struct school school_var;
the compiler now allocate the required bytes in the stack memory as 1 char* and 3 int variables with their name(name,student,teacher,worker)
or just he deals like allocating in the heap memory giving me empty required memory spaces and i fill one by one ?

Comment: It allocates it in the stack. Now someone will come along and point out that the C specification doesn't say anything about a stack, but it's conceptually like a stack because it's automatically freed when the function returns.

Comment: so the process of allocating and freeing in the stack isn't clearly can be explained?

Comment: The C language just specifies the observable behavior, it doesn't require any specific implementation. Stacks are the most common way to implement local variables, but it's not required.